# Domain without Nameservers- how to find them

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, namespaces

I am a bit new to the servers. I still want to ask one question, and yes I know its a noob question but still... So I bought one domain from amazon AWS. The domain name is droni-bg.eu. Do you know how can I check the correct namespaces and SOA for my domain? I tried to setup, but still does not work with these settings:
[image]
Please help me finish my task. Thanks in advance. I want to add that when I try to hit the given ip from my browser - it works. So that dns setup is the tricky part now.
[image]

SOA looks fine. QUESTION TITLE UPDATED
[image]

Last Config:

[image]

Comment: That's odd, the record is butchered. Why didn't you keep the default value?

Comment: that a nice question and the answer is because I am re****ed, but I already deleted it

Comment: I didn't expect I won't be able to create new one

Comment: There is a example in the doc on the right, just change example.net with your domain. (Hopefully this works since switching the serial can be a pain)

Comment: or I didnt expect amazon will delete the information without the posibility to use the default wizard again

Comment: @eckes the problem is I dont know how to build that thing. Example: 
    ns.example.net. hostmaster.example.com. 1 
    7200 900 1209600 86400

Comment: I dont know the hostmaster nor the right numbers, nor how to retreive them

Comment: if I buy new ***.eu domain I can see the correct info and copy it maybe. But I am sure there is a way without buying new domain.

Comment: that is a major feature for the amazon aws I think. as they gave me the correct setup so easy- there should be a button for setting the default host zones (will be good next to the domains view)

Comment: You can BTW use one of the free DNS test tools like http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/

Comment: does not work I will update the question with the setup screen in a second

Comment: updated. Now can we check the Default namespaces that a domain is getting?

Comment: maybe they are wrong - these 4

Comment: The SOA can be used 1:1, the first entry must be one of the existing nameservers, the second is a email address with @ replaced by ., the numbers can be taken 1:1 (but the serial must be same or larger as the last one amazon has seen)

Comment: What is the problem after changing it?

Comment: @eckes yes I changed the SOA, but still not the namespaces

Comment: I suppose they are random too

Comment: Sorry I don't understand? What namespaces? There is nothing random in the SOA. Do you get a error message, if yes what?

Comment: Do you mean you changed the NS records? Have you tried the Test button at the top? If you changed the name records I am afraid you would have to involve AWS support to get them restored

Comment: I will check the route53 console for a test domain later to see if there is a way to restore this stuff.

Comment: SOA looks perfect, namespaces I tried to get by querying my given ip

Comment: 34.206.198.206 with a random tool that gave me these namespaces

Comment: NS means nameservers not namespaces. Only amazon can tell you which are the right ones.

Comment: aftraid that strategy does not work :(

Comment: nameservers. I am very far from networking I am pure backend java and sql and product owner and now

Comment: I have to setup that test environment so a journalist to take a look at the woocomerse that I setup so he do seo for a business

Comment: and that delete of the hosted zones... can't be... amazon have a big defect in the software if it is imposible to recover easy

Comment: I think there should be a way to query the nameservers for the given domain name isn't it?

Comment: I added ananswer, the most important part is the last senence :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57577/discussion-between-eckes-and-gen-strash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SOA and NS records are critical for the functioning of a DNS zone.

The SOA record contains some timeouts (you can use the defaults as listed in the example), it contains a email address in case somebody wants to contact the administrator of the zone. You can put any of your e-mails there, by default an email like hostmaster@droni-eu.bg is used. There is one specialty: you must replace the '@' sign in the email address with a '.'. The first entry should be the name of your primary nameserver. It could be something like ns.droni-eu.bg, but I would pick the first AWS name server (see below). The last parameter which is important is the serial number, it can only go up. In your case it is 1, but each change might change it, and if you put a date there you might need to use the next day (i.e. numerically increase it). (but since dates are uncommon on route53 I would try 1 and see if it propagates anyway).

```
SOA Value: ns-720.awsdns-26.net. hostmaster.droni-bg.eu. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
```

The NS records describe the name servers for your zone. They are typically assigned by your DNS hoster, in that case AWS. If you dont know what name servers amazon has assigned you you can go to the Route53 console in the Zone overview, if you click on your public zone the text box on the right will list you the name servers. Here is a sample with mine:

[image]

This is also described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/SOA-NSrecords.html

The NS provisioned by AWS are different for each AWS customer/zone but they have to be the ones assigned by AWS for your domain.

The same NS will also have to be entered in the parent zone. Currently the following nameservers are known by the parent zone (I asume AWS set them so they should be the same as you see in the console):

```
$ dig ns droni-bg.eu @nl.dns.eu

droni-bg.eu.            86400   IN      NS      ns-720.awsdns-26.net.
droni-bg.eu.            86400   IN      NS      ns-1608.awsdns-09.co.uk.
droni-bg.eu.            86400   IN      NS      ns-109.awsdns-13.com.
droni-bg.eu.            86400   IN      NS      ns-1366.awsdns-42.org.
```

These servers currently refuse queries for the zone, this might be because you they have been removed from the NS record. If they are the same as listed on the overview paged and you have entered them it should work. If not you need to contact AWS support and tell them to re-enable it. If you have a basic account I would at least try a [forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=87), you will not be able to fix Amazons name servers if the need a kick.

BTW: the order of NS records does not matter, but I would put the first one from the overview page first in the NS records and copy it to the SOA record (for other DNS providers there is a clear distinction between primary and secondaries, I guess AWS does not need that)

Comment: still can't make it work :( changed to these. I also read the article. Amazon is giving endpoint to querry all my existing hosted zones, but not all the transaction, so that wont work too.

Comment: Maybe the amazon are hiding it

Comment: behind firewall or something

Comment: i will update my new config in a minute

Comment: updated it with a screenshot of the last config

Comment: @gen.Strash Contact AWS about this. As in your other question, you're proving that you have no desire to actually understand any of this, but rather are just looking to get free consulting.

Comment: @EEAA I want to understand, how did you judge such things thats more weird

Comment: I want to understand how to query information that should be public for my account

Comment: I can use endpoints without guis very well but I dont see such an endpoint or posibility. I dont want support for smomething that should be public, isn't it

Comment: and I don't want free consulting I am asking stack overflow network and here is no way to pay. And I don't want to ask amazon if it is possible the other way- its also interesting if there is a way around it

Comment: 1) You removed the NS records. You'll need to contact AWS to verify what they should be set to. 2) If you don't want to use a GUI, all AWS products have full API support.